# Unable to access certain elements in page in Code behind using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following code shows a part of my webpage.

```
<h3 ID = "pageno">Page <%=PageNumber%> of <%=MaxPageNumber()%></h3> 

<asp:Button ID="btnPrevPage" runat="server" Text="Prev Page" Class="Shape1" OnClick="onPrevPageClick" />  
<asp:Button ID="btnNextPage" runat="server" Text="Next Page" Class="Shape1" OnClick="onNextPageClick" />
```

In the code behind, I am using the following code.

```
btnPrevPage.Visible = false;
btnNextPage.Visible = false;
pageno.Visible = false;
```

The problem is the buttons are getting hidden whereas when the third line to hide the page no, when I include that in the code, it throws the following error  **CS0103: The name 'pageno' does not exist in the current context. How do I fix this?**

The full stack trace is as follows

```
    Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'pageno' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:


Line 37:        BlogEntries1.SetData(myDataSet, "");
Line 38:        
Line 39:        pageno.Visible = false;
Line 40:        btnPrevPage.Visible = false;
Line 41:        btnNextPage.Visible = false;

Source File: c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\casts-alt\blog\blog2.aspx.cs    Line: 39
```

Comment: you can't access any element in code without runat="server" in design

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `runat` attribute in order to access the element in code behind

```
 <h3 ID = "pageno" runat="server">Page <%=PageNumber%> of <%=MaxPageNumber()%></h3>
```